# Consulta para seleccionar primer registro tanto en PostgreSQL como en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, postgresql

Necesito seleccionar el primer registro de una consulta. Pero el problema es que con `top 1` solo me funciona en *SQL Server*, mas no en *PostgreSQL*. Y en *PostgreSQL* me funciona con `limit` pero en *SQL Server* no. Estos son los ejemplos. Les agradecería mucho si saben de alguna forma de cómo generar esta consulta para los dos tipos de bases de datos.

**PostgreSQL:**

```
 SELECT c.crgo_id,c.crgo_nombre
            FROM workflow w 
            JOIN etapaworkflow ew ON w.wrko_id = ew.wrko_id 
            JOIN etapacargo ec ON ew.tpawrko_id = ec.tpawrko_id 
            JOIN cargo c ON c.crgo_id = ec.crgo_id 
            WHERE w.wrko_id = 3 AND ec.tpacrgo_backup = 'NO' 
            ORDER BY ec.tpawrko_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 c.crgo_id,c.crgo_nombre 
            FROM workflow w 
            JOIN etapaworkflow ew ON w.wrko_id = ew.wrko_id 
            JOIN etapacargo ec ON ew.tpawrko_id = ec.tpawrko_id 
            JOIN cargo c ON c.crgo_id = ec.crgo_id 
            WHERE w.wrko_id = 1 AND ec.tpacrgo_backup = 'NO' 
            ORDER BY ec.tpawrko_id ASC
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión del SQL Server? Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9241984/4092887).

Comment: Si bien ambos ***SGBDR*** (***RDBMS*** en inglés) se basan en el lenguaje **SQL**, eso no quiere decir que los dos se ajusten exactamente al estándar, es por eso que vemos diferencias entre un motor y otro, porque cada uno implementa mejoras propias. Te conviene determinar hacia qué base de datos irá dirigida la consulta, entonces con un simple `if` podrás elegir la adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente esta versión funcione en ambos:

```
SELECT c.crgo_id,c.crgo_nombre
    FROM workflow w 
    JOIN etapaworkflow ew ON w.wrko_id = ew.wrko_id 
    JOIN etapacargo ec ON ew.tpawrko_id = ec.tpawrko_id 
    JOIN cargo c ON c.crgo_id = ec.crgo_id 
WHERE w.wrko_id = 3 AND ec.tpacrgo_backup = 'NO' 
ORDER BY ec.tpawrko_id ASC
OFFSET  0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Esta es la forma establecida por el estándar SQL:2008 para esta funcionalidad.  Según la respuesta apuntada por @mauricio, SQL Server la implementa desde la versión 2012.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder  pero no me funciona en sql server.

Comment: @Manuel: Como ya te preguntaron en otro comentario, por favor dinos qué versión de SQL Server usas, porque las últimas versiones sí funcionan.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @alvherre es correcta. Pero como comentastes que no te funcionó en SQL Server, debo asumir que tienes una versión anterior a SQL Server 2012.

De ser el caso, creo que la única forma de lograr usar una consulta idéntica para ambos bases de datos es usando `row_number()`:

```
select crgo_id,
       crgo_nombre
  from (select c.crgo_id,
               c.crgo_nombre,
               row_number() over (order by ec.tpawrko_id) as rn
          from workflow w 
          join etapaworkflow ew
            on w.wrko_id = ew.wrko_id 
          join etapacargo ec
            on ew.tpawrko_id = ec.tpawrko_id 
          join cargo c
            on c.crgo_id = ec.crgo_id 
         where w.wrko_id = 1 
           and ec.tpacrgo_backup = 'NO') t
 where rn = 1
```